# Looping through folders and comparing files using win32

Tags: python, winapi, ms-word, docx

Looking to use win32 to compare multiple word docs. The naming convention is the same except the modified doc has test.docx added to the file name. The below is the code i have but it is coming up with "pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023170, 'The remote procedure call failed.', None, None)". Any ideas on how i can get this to work? I have around 200docs to compare so python seems to be the way to do it.

```
import win32com.client
from docx import Document
import os



def get_docx_list(dir_path):
    '''
    :param dir_path:
    :return: List of docx files in the current directory
    '''
    file_list = []
    for path,dir,files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith("docx") == True and str(file[0]) != "~":  #Locate the docx document and exclude temporary files
                file_root = path+"\\"+file
                file_list.append(file_root)
    print("The directory found a total of {0} related files!".format(len(file_list)))
    return file_list


def main():
    modified_path = r"C:\...\Replaced\SWI\\"
    original_path = r"C:\...\Replaced\SWI original\\"

    for i, file in enumerate(get_docx_list(modified_path), start=1):
        print(f"{i}、Files in progress:{file}")
        for i, files in enumerate(get_docx_list(original_path), start=1):
            Application = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")

            Application.CompareDocuments(
                 Application.Documents.Open(modified_path + file),
                 Application.Documents.Open(str(original_path) + files))
            Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(FileName=modified_path + files + "Comparison.docx")
            Application.Quit()

      
      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone chasing the solution to do bulk word comparisons below is the code I successfully ran through a few hundred docs. Delete the print statements once you have the naming convention sorted.

```
import win32com.client
import os

def main():
    #path directories
    modified_path = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Replaced\SOP- Plant and Equipment\\"
    original_path = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Replaced\SOP - Plant and Equipment Original\\"
    save_path = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Replaced\TEST\\"
    file_list1 = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Replaced\SOP- Plant and Equipment\\")
    file_list2 = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Replaced\SOP - Plant and Equipment Original\\")
    #text counter
    Number = 0
    
    #loop through files and compare
    for file in file_list1:
        for files in file_list2:
            #if files match do comparision, naming convention to be changed
            if files[:-5] + " test.docx" == file:
                Number += 1
                print(f"The program has completed {Number} of a total of {len(file_list1)} related files!")
                try:
                    Application = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
                    Application.CompareDocuments(
                        Application.Documents.Open(modified_path + file),
                        Application.Documents.Open(str(original_path) + files))
                    Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = 3
                    Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(FileName=save_path + files[:-5] + " Comparison.docx")

                except:
                    Application.Quit()
                    pass






if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: At a minimum an answer must explain what the issue is, and how the proposed solution addresses it. *"Try this"* type of answers aren't generally useful.